# How is my Java code compiled if my CLASSPATH variable is empty?

Tags: java, classpath

I know that `$CLASSPATH` includes a list of paths where Java compiler looks for jar files to use their classes.

When I type: `echo $CLASSPATH` I get an empty line, meaning that `CLASSPATH` is empty.

Now, I wrote the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayList.add("Hello");
        System.out.println(arrayList);        
    }
}
```

and compiled it with the command:

```
javac Main.java
```

The file compiled successfully. If the `CLASSPATH` is empty, how did java compiler find the class `java.util.ArrayList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Oracle documentation:

> The CLASSPATH variable is one way to tell applications, including the
>   JDK tools, where to look for user classes. (Classes that are part of
>   the JRE, JDK platform, and extensions should be defined through other
>   means, such as the bootstrap class path or the extensions directory.)

So, `classpath` is actually for user classes and `ArrayList` is part of JDK. Also:

> The default value of the class path is ".", meaning that only the
>   current directory is searched

For full description take a look here: [java paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Comment: OK. How can I see bootstrap class path ?

Comment: @CrazySynthax I guess you could use `java` `-Xbootclasspath` option if you wanted to change it ([X options](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html))... but what for? Default are usually fine... to find out which are the defaults - I suppose you could google a little...